# pgAdmin Table not showing in database after successfull migration

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to create a REST API using psql and Django , i've reached the stage of applying migrations to add tables to my database, these migrations are successfull but when i open pgadmin to view my database their are no tables no matter how many times i refresh.

Below is how i run the migrations:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations ExampleApp`
2. `python manage.py migrate ExampleApp`

Any help would be much appreciated as I am completely lost at this stage :)

[image: table not showing any new tables afte migration img]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you would have not saved your settings file before making migrations. I was facing the same issue, on inspecting I found out that I ran the migrations without saving the settings.py file. After saving it and rerunning the commands my issue was resolved. Hopefully it helps.